# How to merge two parameters in bash (using pcgrep or other)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, grep

I have some files in one folder with this text information:

```
To verify that you own email@domain.info, please click here.
You may be asked to enter this confirmation code: 54373
```

How I can merge this information and get only this in formal email:code. As a result, I want to have this:

```
email@domain.info:54373
```

I tried to use this:

```
pcregrep -oM '(?<=To\ verify\ that\ you\ own\ )[\w\W]*?(?=,\ please\ click\ here\.)' * | pcregrep -oM '(?<=You\ may\ be\ asked\ to\ enter\ this\ confirmation\ code:\ ).*' *
```

But I have only code without my format.

Answer (score 0):

Since:

```
$ grep -o '[^ ]*@[^,]*' a
email@domain.info
$ awk -F: 'END{print $NF}' a
 54373
```

You can say:

```
email=$(grep -o '[^ ]*@[^,]*' file)
number=$( awk -F: 'END{print $NF}' file)
```

and then

```
echo "$email:$number"
```

Comment: can i do this if i have many files in folder (not one) ? i try but this is doesnt work (because, in files has many email but i need only middle of this text : "To verify that you own email@domain.info, please click here." and 
 last number (in the end of this text) : "You may be asked to enter this confirmation code: 54373"

Comment: @Complike it would be useful then to have a [mcve] that covers all the possible cases. This way we can assist you better.